# Should there be Javascript files when downloading Cloud Functions source code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-console

I am having an issue with a Cloud Function that is returning 401-UNAUTHENTICATED all the time, and I've gone to the Google Cloud Console to download the CF's source code.

Is it normal that the .zip file that you get only contains config files and not `.js` files with the actual code?

For a CF like this:

```js
let app: App | undefined;

export const createRegularUserV1 = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .https.onCall(async (data: CreateRegularUserRequestModel, context) => {
    initializeAppInstance();

    data.constructor = CreateRegularUserRequestModel;
    return await app!.createRegularUser(data);
  });
```

The zip that I got from the Google Cloud Console contained:

```
- firestore-debug.log
- jest.config.js
- package.json
- package.lock.json
- pubsub-debug.log
- remoteconfig.template.json
- tsconfig.dev.json
- tsconfig.json
- ui-debug.log
- .env
```

It seems to me that these files are all related to Typescript, testing and logging. It does not make sense to me that these are uploaded when deploying a CF. And, more importantly, shouldn't here be the actual JS being executed (or at least TS)?

Comment: If I do: Google Cloud Console -> Cloud Functions -> Selects a function in the list -> Select the tab "Source" -> Download, then I get a zip of all source files that were part of that deployment. I get .js and .map files and all my files are written in ts.

Comment: Thanks @JW_, as it turns out, the problem comes when I unzip the file. For some reason, my unzip program is not extracting files in folders. As a result, when I unzipped the file I only got the files in the root folder, and the folders in the root but empty.

Comment: Hello, have you tried with another program to unzip? If this is the case what was your result?